# Replace the whole sting in dataframe if it matches the pattern

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to replace the value in df if this value contains a partial string.
My solution:

```
stimuli_dict = {'121': 'mp4', '212': 'mp3'}
stimuli_dict = {r"^{}".format(k): v for k, v in stimuli_dict.items()}

df['stimulus'] = df['stimulus'].replace(stimuli_dict, regex=True)
```

But it replaces only the partial string in a column. I want to replace the entire string with a dictionary value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can add .* into your keys it would solve your problem. It is about regular expression. You need to tell that we are looking for something starts with 121 and rest is not important.

```
stimuli_dict = {'121.*': 'mp4', '212.*': 'mp3'}
```

"." means any character, "*" means previous character between zero and unlimited times. for further explanations, you can check regular expressions.

Comment: The question says "if this value contains a partial string".  Suggested regex patterns do not replace characters prior to 121 or 212 i.e. only those afterward.  Would suggest '.*121.*' and ".*212.*' to get contains.

Comment: But in the beginning if you look at regex, (s)he used "^" which means the searched value should be the beginning. So,  ".*" in the beginning is unneccessary.

Comment: That is a good point.